# twisted http client

Tags: python, http, client, twisted

I am after an example describing the usage of Twisted's HTTP Client.

After reading the excellent [blog post on the internals of Twisted](http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327), I understand how the "Factory" and "Protocol" components play their role but I am unclear on how to introduce "Request" in the overall Client flow.

More specifically, I need to be able to perform HTTP GET and POST requests to a remote server using Twisted.

**Updated**: after a discussion on irc #twisted / #python, it seems that `twisted.web2` is fading away in favor of beefing up functionality on `twisted.web` e.g. Agent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Twisted 9.0, there are actually two HTTP clients available.  The older one has quite a few features, such as automatically following redirects, interpreting cookie headers, etc.  You can find an example of its usage here:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples/

(`getpage.py` and `dlpage.py`)

Unfortunately, the interface presented by the older client makes a number of common tasks difficult.  For example, using `getPage`, you cannot examine arbitrary response headers.

The newer HTTP client isn't yet as featureful as the old one, but it presents an interface intended to eliminate the limitations of `getPage`.  It is also intended to be more easily extended and customized.  You can find a document describing its usage here:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html

Comment: Marvelous! Exactly what I need!

Comment: ...except it is only available in 9.0.0... arhhh!

Comment: Would you prefer that we stop improving, so that new versions don't contain anything good? :)

Comment: Are there any samples available on issuing post requests with a content-type of multipart/form-data ?

Comment: Does `Agent` follow redirects by default?

Answer (score 2):

I started using treq with twisted. treq has an API which is very similar to Requests.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treq/0.2.0

Answer (score 1):

As of Twisted 10, you may want to use the `Agent` class.

Please follow this link:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/web/howto/client.html